# Small Probabilities in Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

I am trying to implement Naive Bayes, but I am encountering a problem. I have 5000 word features. Hence, every sample is a binary vector of length 5000. The true labels are 1 or 0. The value of P(feature=1 | label=1) and P(feature=0 | label=1) are very small (~0.03) as the feature vector is very sparse. When I calculate the numerator i.e.

```
P(features | label=1) * P(label=1)
```

since, the probability values are very small and because of the conditional independence assumption of Naive Bayes, when I multiply 2000 such small terms, I get 0 and hence, a wrong result. What should be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two most commonly used techniques to prevent underflows with a naive Bayes classifier are:

1. Working in the log space
2. Using the log-sum-exp trick

More details: [Example of how the log-sum-exp trick works in Naive Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253319/12359)

---

FYI:

- [With the Naive Bayes classifier, why do we have to normalize the probabilities after calculating the probabilities of each hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249762/12359)
- [Softmax Regression Large Inner Product Float Overflow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/160963/12359)

Comment: I did the summation of log probabilities. But, the sum of log probabilities comes out ot be -100000. Still, the answer comes out to be wrong as log P = -100000 and hence P would be 0. What should I do now?

Comment: @Hellboy What do you want to do with P?

Comment: Since, it is a binary classifier, I'll compare P with 0.5, if it is greater than 0.5, I'll assign positive label to the test sample.

Comment: @Hellboy How about comparing log P with log 0.5?

Comment: Yes, but every sample is being classified as a negative sample as every sum is less than log 0.5

Comment: @Hellboy how about using the maximum a posteriori (MAP) decision rule? ([Example of how the log-sum-exp trick works in Naive Bayes](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253319/12359) 1st bullet point)