# With the Naive Bayes classifier, why do we have to normalize the probabilities after calculating the probabilities of each hypothesis?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, normalization, naive-bayes

In the Naive Bayes classifier, why do we have to normalize the probabilities after calculating the probabilities of each hypothesis?

Comment: If you want to have the responsibility of each class for a single datapoint, you must normalize to 1, otherwise it can not be interpreted as a probability.

Comment: This question appears to be squarely on-topic to me - it's about probability and statistics.

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/129666/103153

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to normalize the probabilities if you only care about knowing which class ($\hat{y}$) your input ($\mathbf{x}=x_1, \dots, x_n$) most likely belongs to, since the maximum a posteriori (MAP) decision rule  is as follows:

$\hat{y} = \underset{k \in \{1, \dots, K\}}{\operatorname{argmax}}p(C_k \vert x_1, \dots, x_n) =  \underset{k \in \{1, \dots, K\}}{\operatorname{argmax}} \ p(C_k) \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \vert C_k)$

[Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)

$$\begin{align}
p(C_k \vert x_1, \dots, x_n) & \varpropto p(C_k, x_1, \dots, x_n) \\
                             & \varpropto p(C_k) \ p(x_1 \vert C_k) \ p(x_2\vert C_k) \ p(x_3\vert C_k) \ \cdots \\
                             & \varpropto p(C_k) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \vert C_k)\,.
\end{align}$$

If you do want the class probabilities, then you indeed need to normalize:

$p(C_k \vert x_1, \dots, x_n) = ~\frac{p(C_k) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \vert C_k)\,}{ \sum_{1 \leq j \leq |C|}{ \left( p(C_j) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \vert C_j\,)   \right) }}$

But keep in mind that, from {1}

> the winning class in NB classification usually has a much larger probability than the other classes and the estimates diverge very significantly from  the true probabilities. NB classifiers
>   estimate badly, but often classify well.

---

References:

- {1} Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze. "[Introduction to Information Retrieval.](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/)" 2009, chapter 13 *Text classification and Naive Bayes*.